# C - Implementing Undo on a board game

Tags: c

I need to implement a better C function to save states of a (simple) board game I am developing. I am using a fixed size (7 x 7) board. Each cell is defined as:

```
struct board {
struct pwn pawn[3];
short unsigned size;
};
```

pwn is defined as a simple tuple containing a boolean and a short;

My question is wether I can implement an Undo (and maybe a Redo) function without using too much space. Currently I was thinking of using a stack ADT to store byte-sized arrays structured as follows

```
typedef struct stringtrace {
    char x, y;
    char *pl;//these are of size 3 max, no dimension needed
    char *off;
} stringtrace;
```

and just use it as an array, but i feel it takes both too long and takes up way too much space, hence I have to delimit it to 20 or so moves to redo (due to crappy budget pc).

Is there a way to keep the memory count down ? I was maybe thinking to use a FILE* function , but I was advised against using gets() and such functions for security reasons. I am very open to suggestions

Comment: Why do you think that will take too much memory even for a low end PC? You haven't really described what the board game moves are and how that is represented by the data structure. But as shown the `stringtrace` struct doesn't look very large.

Answer (score 1):

On a 64-bit machine, your undo struct requires 24 bytes if pointers are aligned at 8-byte boundaries.  With 2 kilobytes you could have almost 100 levels of undo, using an array.  Are you sure that's not enough?

For small data structures like your undo list, arrays are almost always the right answer these days.  Anything else you do will require more code, and it won't take long before your code size exceeds any size savings. If, indeed, you manage any savings at all.  While it doesn't likely matter for this application, arrays fit nicely with caches, too, so you get better performance for writing simple code.

If you wanted, oh, a million levels of undo, you could create a 2 MB file and use **mmap**(2).  That's leaves the RAM page allocation up to the OS, depending on machine size, and still leaves you with a simple array.

Comment: Furthermore, as the board is 7x7 you can store both the x and y value into 8 (well 6 really) bits, eliminating the other char. I am sure you can optimize the pointers away from the structure as well, if more details are given, which take up the bulk of the space. EDIT: But then again, the space conern for a "PC" is most likely a non-issue